# Do you know where is AllocateDASD registry in Windows 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Until `Windows 2012`, there is `MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AllocateDASD` but it doesn't exist on `Windows 2016`.

Do you know where it is?

Answer (score 0):

The `AllocateDASD` registry value is only created when you configure the Local Security Policy setting "Devices: Allowed to format and eject removable media".

This has not changed in Windows 2016.